# Can I stretch or expand an entire standalone document to fit the page?

Tags: formatting, scaling, standalone, article, layout

If I create a standalone document, and it's approximately the shape of an A4 piece of paper, can I expand it to take up a full page; stretch it to fit the dimensions of the an A4 article? Just want to stretch to fit the whole thing without fiddling around with it if possible.

As I understand it, LaTeX PDFs are scalable like that, but I don't know if it's something the LaTeX will accomodate. I have other ways of achieving the goal, but I'd like to see if it's possible with LaTeX first.

I didn't originally intend to do more than a couple of little standalone graphics but over time I added to it. I don't want to have to go through restructuring and formatting, etc. because a) I finally have it (almost) exactly how I like it, except for this new scaling issue. And b) it will be considerably time consuming to do it now.

In other words, it started as "fit-page-to-contents", but now I want to "fit-contents-to-page". I'm using `\tabular` and `\booktabs` if that helps.

Here's an example of what it looks like as a standalone:

[image]

Here's what it look's like if I force it back into article mode

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[margin=6]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,booktabs,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape Head Section} \\
\midrule
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture} \\
$\alpha$&$\alpha$ \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape Section One} \\
\midrule
$\begin{gathered}
\textsc{Left Side}  \\
\midrule
  \begin{aligned}
  X(x)&=(1,0,1,0,1) \\
  Y(y)&=(1,0,1,0,1) \\
  \midrule
  \delta&=0 \ \ |  \ \ 
  \Delta=0 \\
  \end{aligned}
\end{gathered}$ &
$\begin{gathered}
\textsc{Right Side} \\
\midrule
  \begin{aligned}
  X(x)&=(1,0,1,0,1) \\
  Y(y)&=(1,0,1,0,1) \\
  \midrule
  \delta&=0 \ \ |  \ \ 
  \Delta=0 \\
  \end{aligned}
\end{gathered}$
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape Section Two} \\
\midrule
$\begin{gathered}
\textsc{Xx \& Yy} \\
\midrule
  \begin{aligned}
  xyxyxy \ 
  xyxyxy \\
  \end{aligned}
\end{gathered}$ &
$\begin{gathered}
\textsc{Xx \& Yy} \\
\midrule
  \begin{aligned}
  xyxyxy \ 
  xyxyxy \\
  \end{aligned}
\end{gathered}$
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape Section Three} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\Omega$} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\xleftarrow{}\ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}
        \ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}\ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}
        \ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}$} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\xleftarrow{}\ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}
        \ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}\ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}
        \ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}$} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape Tail Section} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{%
$\begin{array}{@{} c *{5}{@{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} c @{}} } 
\ \  \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ 
       & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \\
\ \  \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ 
       & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \\
\end{array}$%
} \\
\bottomrule[\lightrulewidth]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `standalone` when the size is as large as an A4 paper? Don't overuse `standalone`!

Comment: Well you can box the content and scale the box. The easiest way would to use adjustbox with width=210mm, height=297,keepaspectratio

Comment: @MartinScharrer That sounds perfect. If you can expand it into an answer, I'll give you the big green tick. In the meantime, I'll try to find more info using the key words gleaned from your comment.

Comment: @JouleV If you read beyond the title, you'll see I included a preemptive answer to your question at the end there. Basically I built upon something small and kept adding notes until it eventually became big enough to fill a page. It started as one thing and evolved into something else.

Comment: @MartinScharrer So how do I apply that to the whole document?

Comment: I wouldn't scale the content - this could distort it - but put eg a minipage of the right size around it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would. Do you know how to? I'll try the other thing too though. I don't really know how to do either though.

Comment: I certainly know how to do it. But you didn't provide a complete minimal example so don't expect code from me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer A complete minimal example of what? That's what I'm looking for. A complete minimal example. Doesn't really matter the content. Something super basic would do, so that way, anyone reading it can just apply or adapt the technique to their own work.

Comment: Well if something super basic would do as start point, why don't you provide it? But beside this: due to the working of standalone it is actually important to know how you create currently the outer box.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sounds like double handling to me. I can't really post the content of my assignment yet, but I'm happy to whip up a template with some lorem ipsum, if you think that would be helpful/useful. Or if you don't have the time or patience, you could just point me to the relevant docs and I'll write an answer.

Comment: I take it you want one page to be significantly larger that the text area.  The easiest is to use a tikzpicture with [overlay, remember picture] and place a node at (current page.center).  \afterpage{\thispagestyle{empty} ...} will help.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365488/include-pdf-page-in-different-geometry-page

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How's this?

Comment: Better. Beside others it helped me to see that I misunderstood the question. I thought the content is already nearly a4. But as it is quite small you will have to resize the box too as Martin suggested. I will add some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use adjustbox to resize your content to nearly a4. And then use a minipage to force the papersize to be exactly a4. Personally I probably wouldn't do it like this but import the document with pdfpages in another document, imho this is less trouble.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t][29.7cm][c]{21cm}
\vspace{0pt}\centering
\adjustbox{max totalheight=29.7cm}{\adjustbox{min width=21cm}{%
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape Head Section} \\
\midrule
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture} \\
$\alpha$&$\alpha$ \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape Section One} \\
\midrule
$\begin{gathered}
\textsc{Left Side}  \\
\midrule
  \begin{aligned}
  X(x)&=(1,0,1,0,1) \\
  Y(y)&=(1,0,1,0,1) \\
  \midrule
  \delta&=0 \ \ |  \ \
  \Delta=0 \\
  \end{aligned}
\end{gathered}$ &
$\begin{gathered}
\textsc{Right Side} \\
\midrule
  \begin{aligned}
  X(x)&=(1,0,1,0,1) \\
  Y(y)&=(1,0,1,0,1) \\
  \midrule
  \delta&=0 \ \ |  \ \
  \Delta=0 \\
  \end{aligned}
\end{gathered}$
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape Section Two} \\
\midrule
$\begin{gathered}
\textsc{Xx \& Yy} \\
\midrule
  \begin{aligned}
  xyxyxy \
  xyxyxy \\
  \end{aligned}
\end{gathered}$ &
$\begin{gathered}
\textsc{Xx \& Yy} \\
\midrule
  \begin{aligned}
  xyxyxy \
  xyxyxy \\
  \end{aligned}
\end{gathered}$
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape Section Three} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\Omega$} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\xleftarrow{}\ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}
        \ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}\ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}
        \ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}$} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\xleftarrow{}\ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}
        \ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}\ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}
        \ \ \ \ \ \ \xleftarrow{}$} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape Tail Section} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{%
$\begin{array}{@{} c *{5}{@{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} c @{}} }
\ \  \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \
       & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \\
\ \  \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \
       & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \to \ & \ \ \ \\
\end{array}$%
} \\
\bottomrule[\lightrulewidth]
\end{tabular}}}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. Can you show the alternative too? The way you said you'd do it? I'll try it both ways and share the results.